# Magento 2 Confirmation Emails Being Blocked by Hotmail accounts

Tags: magento2, email, order-email

Order confirmation emails on our Magento 2 store are not being recieved by customers who use hotmail email addresses. They are coming through to Google Apps accounts and gmail users. We've recently moved the site to a new VPS and this is when the issue seems to have started. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Facing same issue with hotmail. U need to be careful with `From` Email-Address.

Comment: Have you resolved it?

Comment: Did you get this resolved? We are having the same problem but I hadn't yet put it down to the fact we moved to a VPS, was this the reason? We have been told by our developer that we have no control over the receiving server which although makes sense seems an unacceptable explanation as there are many email providers this affects. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you resolve it?. Am also having the same issue.